# Escaping ampersand within a string variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am replacing the text `SUBJECT` with a value from an array variable like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# array of subjects, the ampersand causes a problem.
subjects=("Digital Art" "Digital Photography" "3D Modelling & Animation")

echo $subjects[2] # Subject: 3D Modelling & Animation

sed -i -e "s/SUBJECT/${subjects[2]}/g" test.svg
```

Instead of replacing the text `SUBJECT`, the resulting text looks like this:

```
3D Modelling SUBJECT Animation
```

How can I include the ampersand as a literal `&` in sed and also have it echo correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is presence of `&` in your replacement text. `&` makes `sed` place fully matched text in replacement hence `SUBJECT` appears in output.

You can use this trick:

```
sed -i "s/SUBJECT/${subjects[2]//&/\\&}/g" test.svg
```

`${subjects[2]//&/\\&}` replaces each `&` with `\&` in 2nd element of `subjects` array before invoking `sed` substitution.

Comment: Thanks! For the .svg file, it needed to be replaced with &amp; so this works: "//&/\\&amp;"

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the `&` in the parameter expansion:

```
sed -i -e "s/SUBJECT/${subjects[2]//&/\\&}/g" test.svg
```

This will expand as follows:

```
$ echo "${subjects[2]//&/\\&}"
3D Modelling \& Animation
```

and if there is no `&`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e "s/SUBJECT/${subjects[2]//&/\\&}/g" test.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

reserved corrector & ampersand problem fix.

here is the example  `sed -i 's+MY_TOKEN+TEST&+g' test.txt`
cat test.txt

TESTMY_TOKEN

to fix the behavior

```
sed -i 's+MY_TOKEN+TEST\&+g' test.txt
```

cat text.txt

TEST&